PowerBi Vertical Monitor Data Display
Is it possible to have PowerBi expand veritcally to display more data? I have roughly 90 lines of data that I would like to view at the same time (the lines don't fit in , however, when I use my vertical monitor the data set doesn't change vertically, it just squishes to fit within the confines of the horizontal allowance on the vertical screen. It seems like PowerBi is only able to be in a 16:9 format? It also wouldn't be reasonable to export an Excel of the PowerBi whenever I need to view the data. I have clicked 'full screen' and 'fit to page' to no avail.
I dragged the page over to the vertical screen and expected PowerBi to fill the veritcal speace similar to that of Word or Excel, but the report stayed in the 16:9 format.
TL;DR: I have 90 lines of data that I would like to read at once on a vertical screen. PowerBi seems to be unable to accommodate. Is it possible to have PowerBi expand to make use of vertical space similar to that of other microsoft tools?
